Stripe Checkout page - 3rd Party Integration
I want to build an API that can access stripe's hosted checkout page if i am a 3rd party provider to the business. i want to add an "upsell" button to the checkout page.
Is this possible, and if so, what programming languages would you use to accomplish something like this?
would you create an application and put it on Stripe's App Marketplace?
thank you!
You can add a "upsell" option if you have a stripe account, but i would like to add the button as a 3rd party.
I know its possible of i create a customer checkout page, but wanted to see if there was an easier and scalable option.

This isn't something you'd be able to do as Checkout is a Stripe hosted page. There's no way to inject your own code to run. Pretty sure that'd be a security risk for Stripe. The ideal way to do this would be to build your own custom page.
